# How to duplicate audio device

Tags: windows-10, audio, surround-sound, stereo, digital-audio

The situation is as follows:
I recently bought [Sennheiser GSX 1000](https://en-ca.sennheiser.com/audio-amplifier-gsx-1000). The device has two main modes: 7.1 and 2.1.

- The 2.1 supports 24bit, 96000Hz (Studio Quality) input. This setting I use for listening to music on my Hi-fi headphones and speakers
- The 7.1 supports up to 16bit, 48000Hz (DVD Quality) input. This setting is useful for games which support 7.1 audio and movies with 7.1 audio

In order to utilize the full potential of the device, the sound settings in the windows need to be set up  accordingly [in this order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9iQL.png):

1. [Default audio Format needs to be changed (Speaker properties / Advanced / Default Format)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4RlF.png)
2. [Setup the audio configuration accordingly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpE2U.png)

It is so annoying to keep reconfiguring the settings since I spend the whole day on the computer and do something different every so often.

I am already used to switching different audio devices via hotkeys by using a program called [SoundSwitch](https://soundswitch.com).

**My goal is to create a second audio device of GSX 1000 Main Audio (e.g. Speakers surround) and have each device set up the way described above.**

Can you help me how can I create duplicate device with different settings so I can use the SoundSwitch accordingly? [The output should look like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJreW.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

All in all, you appear to be trying to work around a problem that doesn't really exist.

If your stereo audio source isn't 24/96 [very very few are] you are wasting your time.
Your DAC can only convert what it's given. Setting it higher is of no benefit if you're not feeding it that data.
If your source is MP3, AAC or net radio there is even less reason to change it.

Setting it to 16/48 is a fair compromise, as re-sampling 44.1<->48 for 'CD vs movie' is these days pretty seamless [it was an issue 15-20 years ago, but no longer].

Additionally, if you feed 2.0 audio to a 7.1 output device, you will get 2.0 audio, unless something in-circuit tries to get 'clever'. If it does, switch off the 'clever'.
What you are left with is the simple requirement of switching outputs on demand, the rest can take care of itself. SoundSwitch seems to be payware; there's a perfectly good freeware output switcher, [Audio Switcher](https://audioswit.ch/er), which can toggle on key command.

Comment: For my music setup, I am either streaming Tidal Hi-Fi or listening to lots of downloaded /ripped music in FLAC format with a bitrate around 1500kbps so setting it up really makes an audible difference, especially with my 800USD headphones.
Trust me, I tried sending 2.0 audio to the device and it cannot replicate the surround experience as well as sending there directly 7.1. The device is specially designed to handle 8 channels for immerse surround with additional gaming EQ enhancement. The device also serves the purpose of a "stupid" amplifier for either headphones and also input microphone.

Comment: Tidal is 16/44.1 or less - https://support.tidal.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002599997-What-Audio-Quality-Does-TIDAL-HiFi-Offer- With FLAC you have no idea what the original format was, as no 'official' source releases on FLAC. Sending 2.0 should *never* have any surround aspect, it's 2.0. regular stereo. If you want some kind of enforced surround aspect, then you're not listening to source audio anyway. My initial reply still stands. btw, 'MQA' is advertising waffle to get you to pay for it.